# Passing Image name from Json with React

Tags: json, reactjs

[image]Hello everyone I am trying to display JSON data with react. All the data from Json apart from image name are displayed without any problem.Can you please tell me where I am wrong?

[image]
Json file and image are in the same directory therefore I thought img src="../banana.jpg" would be ok.

Here my js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ProductInfo from '../plist.json'

class Products extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {ProductInfo.map((postDetail, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <h1>{postDetail.name}</h1>
                    <p>{postDetail.price}</p>
                    <p>{postDetail.description}</p>
                    <img src="../{postDetail.image}" alt="Product Image"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Products
```

and here Json file

```
[
   {
      "name":"Banana",
      "price":"3,99",
      "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt.",
      "image":"banana.jpg",
      "profileUrl":"#"
   },
     {
      "name":"Apple",
      "price":"1,99",
      "description":"Sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.",
      "image":"apple.jpg",
      "profileUrl":"#"
}
]
```

and here the error I get with

[image]

Comment: Have you tried 

 <img src="../{postDetail.image}" alt="Product Image"/>

Comment: This is actually what I have tried but I copied the old version of my code to this question now I changed the question. :) so it didnt work when I inspect the page I see <img src="../{postDetail.image}" alt="Product Image">

Answer (score 0):

Try to require the image, it will tell webpack or whatever bundler to count with the image

```
<img src={require(`../${postDetail.image}`)} />
```

my guess would be that you are poiting at file ../banana.jpg which isnt there once you bundle up your program.

Comment: what does it say in console in devtools? and could you screen your project srtructure?

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/components/main.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../${postDetail.image}' in 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\FrontEnd\React\tutorial\src\components'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: well you have wrong quotes, use the ones I posted ``. you can read what are those in here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Ahh you are right. I have changed the quotes, here what I got

(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/FrontEnd/React/tutorial/src/components/main.js:20
  17 | <h1>{postDetail.name}</h1>
  18 | <p>{postDetail.price}</p>
  19 | <p>{postDetail.description}</p>
> 20 | <img src={require(`../${postDetail.image}`)} />
     | ^  21 | 
  22 | 
  23 | 
View compiled

Comment: @allstar sorry at this point maybe screenshot screenshot or full message would be helpful

Comment: I have added into my question

Comment: @allstar ok right now the image is not there, could you please screenshot the whole project tree and tell me in which file are you trying to load the image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186382/discussion-between-allstar-and-lukas-gibo-vaic).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added the screenshot,

Comment: Please install something like vscode, it will make your life easier. Where is the Products file located?